# How to combine similar signals to generate another one?

Tags: approximation

Assume there are 11 signals. These signals are very similar to each other in both time and frequency domains. (And the similarity between them is not random; they are similar because they have somehow a common source. Actually they are well-correlated.) All these signals have the same number of samples. And I have access to them all.

One of these signals is important for me. (Let's name them S_main & S1~S10)

*Now here's the question:*

- **How can I combine S1 ~ S10 in order to re-generate S_main theoretically !!?**

[Note: S_main itself is available !!! But I want to re-generate it using the combination of S1~S10 , in order to compare the physically-measured S_main to the theoretically-computed S_main.]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We need more information.  What is the relationship of S_main to S1 - S10?

Comment: They are related in terms of amplitude, waveform, frequency, max., min., etc.

Comment: As @JimClay has already pointed out, you need some model how your signals are generated in order to be able to solve your problem. If S_main=-S1, just invert S1, if S_main=a*S1+b*S2, use some optimality criterion to estimate constants a and b, etc.etc. Do you see how arbitrary these "solutions" are? This comes from the fact that your problem is not well-defined.

Comment: Yes, what @MattL said.  We need to know more than just "they are related".  Are they supposed to be the exact same and they just have different noise?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, there's no such clean and clear relation between them. These are some Voltage Signals distributed over a 3D surface. All I say about similarity is based only on what I get when I simply look at the waveforms. I don't know how they are related. (Actually if I knew the relation between them, I would definitely know how to combine them!!). They are 11 different signals, but they all look like each other. That's all I know!!!

Comment: If we talk about a relation or a model, we usually mean a parametric model with some unknown parameters. I.e. you need to know how the signals are related in terms of some model. And even knowing this relation/model, it is usually still not so trivial to solve the estimation problem.

Comment: The model of the signals are fortunately known. They all have the same biological model and have a similar pattern.

Comment: This comes from the fact that your problem is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

If the difference between signals is mostly additive Gaussian noise, you could try averaging together the 10 measured signals to estimate the original.  If there is fat-tailed shot noise, you could try applying a median filter on your 10 measured signals.  If these assumptions are incorrect, then the results may be garbage.

Comment: Thanks hotpaw2 for your answer. Actually the difference between the signals is beyond noise. So I need to do a weighted averaging rather than a simple average. And the question is how to find the weights.